# echo orders from items

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart

I have items in shopping cart that are presented in shopping cart. For example: I have 3 different items with quantity
I managed to echo it out to shopping cart page, and to write an order to ORDERS table.

```
 <?php
 ...
 $sql = "SELECT id_item, item, price FROM id_item WHERE id_item IN (";
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
       $sql .=$id.",";
    }
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY item ASC";
$query =mysql_query($sql);
$total = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $subtotal = $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_item']]['quantity']*$row['price'];
    $total += $subtotal; 
?>
<tr>
    <td width="200px" style="padding-left:20px;"><?= $row['item'] ?></td>
    <td style="padding-left:20px;"><input type="text" name="quantity[<?= $row['id_item']?>]" size="5" value="<?= $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_item']]['quantity']?>"</td>
    <td style="padding-left:20px;"><?= $row['price']?></td>
    <td style="padding-left:20px;"><?= $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_item']]['quantity']*$row['price']?> kn</td>
</tr>
...
```

So now I want to write an order into table ORD.ITEMS and I'm stuck here because it have multiple items.

table ORDERS and ORD.ITEMS have relation on id_order, table ORD.ITEMS and ITEMS have rel on item & id_item

```
 ORDERS
 id_order
 user
 date
 status   -> this I'll try on my own, if status is 0 order is open, if 1 order closed, if 2 order

 ORD.ITEMS
 id_order
 id_ord.items
 item
 quantity

 ITEMS
 id_item
 title
 description
 price
```

so now I want something like this for three differente items:

```
 ORDERS
 1
 user1
 2014-01-01
 0

 ORD.ITEMS
 1
 1
 10
 5 

 ORD.ITEMS
 1
 2
 20
 3

 ORD.ITEMS
 1
 3
 30
 2
```

**How to write SQL query that after finishing order write into table ORD.ITEMS three items?**

Comment: Will you have a confirmation page to add the order?

Comment: yes, I will. And all of that I intend to happen on confirmation page.

Comment: So start creating it, if you will find any problem we are here to help you solve any of them. Just a clue you can loop in your shopping cart array and insert the order and products details accoring

Comment: As a side note, you've got an opportunity for a malicious user to do a massive ***SQL Injection*** attack on your server. Since this is an ecommerce system, I would highly recommend that you review your security and consider using ***prepared statements*** with `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. `mysql_*` commands are ***deprecated*** and should not be used.

Comment: thanx, but I'm using this to practice, tonight I'll finish my project and tomorrow I'll start rewriting it with PDO, using classes and some improvements.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem, it was easy. This is a way I solve it:

```
    $sqlMaxS = "SELECT MAX(id_ord_items) FROM ord.items";
    $resultMaxS = queryDB($sqlMaxS);
    $result = mysql_fetch_row($resultMaxS);
    $id_ord_items = $result['0'];
    $id_ord_items++;


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id_item IN (";

    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
        $sql .=$id.",";
    }

    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";

    $query =mysql_query($sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO ord.items (id_order, id_ord_items, item, quantity)
                VALUES ('$id_order', '$id_ord_items', {$row['id_item']}, {$_SESSION['cart'][$row['id_item']]['quantity']})";
    $stavka++;
    queryDB($sql);
```

just as above I used while loop.